# Alternative to Cooper pairing in superconductivity

Tags: superconductivity

BCS theory, in which electrons form Cooper pairs, has been successful in explaining conventional superconductivity. Physicists have adopted similar pairing mechanism in an attempt to explain high-temperature superconductivity (HTS).

Is there any HTS theory that is not based on pairing? If not, what experiments preclude the existence of such a theory?

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge (if it has any value), there is no such modern theory without pairing.

So the question is *why*, right ?

There is no proposal trying to explain high-temperature superconductors (HTS) without paired electrons for the simple reason that there are (at least supposed, let me know if you disagree) evidences for pairing ! If you know about the Aharonov-Bohm effect, you will not be shocked by two facts

- due to Aharonov-Bohm, there are some quantities which oscillates at the ratio $\Phi /2 \Phi_{0}$, with $\Phi_{0}=h/2e$ the [superconducting flux quantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum), $\Phi$ being the magnetic flux piercing some non-connected region of matter (metal or superconductors in our case of concern). So, for normal electrons some things actually oscillate with the characteristic value of the Planck constant $h$ over the charge of the electron $e$
- there is no known quantity oscillating at $\Phi /2 \Phi_{0}$ for superconductors, *everything is oscillating at $\Phi / \Phi_{0}$, even for HTS*, as for the [Little-Parks effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%E2%80%93Parks_effect) for instance. In short, Little-Parks effect is the oscillation with the magnetic flux of the critical temperature of a superconducting plate with a hole in the middle. All these interfering experiments need the composite particle with charge $2e$ to be understood.

Unfortunately, I can not find some good references discussing this point. I'll try to include some latter. I believe there are some discussions in the book by A.J. Leggett *Quantum Liquids: Bose Condensation and Cooper Pairing in Condensed-Matter Systems* Oxford Graduate Texts.

*edit Haha edit !* I've done the previous answer based on some discussions I had with colleagues. I was (stupidly) looking for *Little-Parks effect + HTS* on Google Scholar without result :-( Of course the good key words to find something are *flux quantisation + HTS*. The first result is already enough I believe

> Gough, C. E., Colclough, M. S., Forgan, E. M., Jordan, R. G., Keene, M., Muirhead, C. M., Rae, A. I. M., et al. *Flux quantization in a high-Tc superconductor.* [Nature, 326(6116), 855–855 (1987)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/326855a0).

Nevertheless, the Leggett's book (that I read when it was first published and forget then) should contains a lot of material in one of its last section. Leggett discusses there all what we know about cuprates.

Comment: Just adding some emphasis to this fine answer. It is clear from many experiments and theory that the superconducting fluid (aka "order parameter") has the same properties as *pairs* of electrons. Specifically the charge of the fluid is $2e$, as demonstrated by Little-Parks. This does not necessarily mean that the electron forms pairs like hydrogen forms $H_2$ molecules, though, it could be more complicated. As long as the result the resulting fluid has the right properties you will reproduce superconductivity as we know it.

Comment: @BebopButUnsteady Thanks for this additional remark. I also want to point out that my answer might well be incomplete. Indeed, the famous pseudogap phase, which I do not know enough, may reserve a lot of surprises...